# foreach throws NullReferenceException on ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, observablecollection, nullreferenceexception

I have `class ElementRelation { ... }` and `class ElementRelationCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ElementRelation> { ... }`

And I have this code:

```
ElementRelationCollection a = ...;
if (a == null)
    throw new Exception("a is null(???)"); // this exception is never thrown
try
{
    foreach (ElementRelation relation in a) // exception is thrown here
    { ... } // never thrown here
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    string message = "Something is null here. a.Count: " + a.Count;
    IEnumerator<ElementRelation> enumerator = a.GetEnumerator();
    message += ", enumerator is " + (enumerator == null ? "null" : "not null");
    throw new Exception(message, ex);
}
```

I can see from the logs that this code sometimes throws an Exception with message
"Something is null here. a.Count: 9, enumerator is  not null". When this starts happening it continues top happen on every page load until I iisreset.

The innerexception of course is a System.NullReferenceException and it has this stacktrace:

```
at MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod() in c:\path\MyClass.cs:line 74
```

where line 74 is the line that says `foreach (ElementRelation relation in a)`

Why does it throw this exception?

**Edit:**

The collection is sometimes updated by a background thread. I thought this could not cause worse problems than a failed iteration but it turns out the whole collection becomes corrupted.

Comment: are you sure your PDBs are up to date according to the source?  Is this a debug or release build?

Comment: also - is this code instance-based, or static?

Comment: What does `ElementRelationCollection` look like? Where's the stack trace?

Comment: Release build. Never seen the error when debugging. The PDB files seem to be up to date. We delete all obj and bin files, do a complete rebuild and publish them all at the same time to the webserver. The line number of the outer exception matches the line number in the code for the line `throw new Exception(message, ex);`

MyClass is can be instantiated and the method is not static.

Comment: ElementRelationCollection doesn't reimplement any of the methods from its base class. It only contains methods that take some input, uses linq to select a subset of the collection and return it. All functions are similar to this: `public ElementRelation GetElementRelationByElementId(int elementId)
 { return this.FirstOrDefault(relation => relation.Element.Id == elementId); }`

Comment: This is the entire stack trace of the NullReferenceException: `at MyNamespace.MyClass.MyMethod() in c:\path\MyClass.cs:line 74` It only contains that one line.

Comment: You're going to have to include a lot more *in the question* a) the stack trace b) what is going on in the foreach c) the code in `ElementRelationCollection` if it implements the enumerable pattern in some non-standard way.

Comment: Are you modifying the collection from a background thread?

Comment: Richard Deeming: That might happen occasionally. I can see how that would cause the loop to fail once. However, it keeps failing every single time the code is run until an iisreset is performed.

casperOne: Ok, will fix it.

Comment: So the collection is shared among different threads?  If so, since `ObservableCollection<T>` is not thread-safe then any manner of exceptions could be raised - including `NullReferenceException`s that, in a release build, appear to have no source other than your code (due to optimizations).

Comment: Yes it's shared. Could that mess up the collection enough that it gets broken beyond repair? Would make more sense if it threw an InvalidOperationException in that case.

Comment: Ok, let's close it here. @RichardDeeming or @andras-zoltan please post the stuff about thread safety as a real answer and get your points. There are some different thread safe alternatives to `ObservableCollection`. Will try them one at a time until I find one that doesn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ObservableCollection<T>` class is not thread-safe. Modifying it from multiple threads can corrupt the internal state to such an extent that it becomes impossible to modify or enumerate the instance.

You will randomly see exceptions such as `NullReferenceException` and `IndexOutOfRangeException` - and that's the best possible result! In other cases, the changes to the collection could be silently dropped.

You will either need to wrap your access to the list in a lock, possibly using [the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx), or switch to a thread-safe collection. For .NET 4.0, the [`System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) has several possibilities.